# Move code into my RecyclerAdapter to prevent NPE

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have this piece of code inside my MainActivity  , what I'm trying to do is to tint a background for an element, it works nice, but the handler is not supposed to do the job of waiting when the views are all inflated, so, I want to move this code inside my onBindViewHolder but Im kinda lost, any hint ?

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListSelectedTAGS.size(); i++) {
                        View view = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(mArrayListaTAGs.indexOf(mArrayListSelectedTAGS.get(i)));
                        view.setBackgroundColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVincular));
                    }

                }
            }, 500);
```

Te question is, how do I get the exact view on my onBindView holder in order to tint it, and how to call it from MainActivity

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same issue , I just solved this with a simple Interface, in my onBindViewHolder, after I bind all my views, I call an interface named `onBindFinished(boolean isFinished);`

after that in my adapter I just set that value to true if the onBind have finished

and in my class the only thing I do is checking if onBindFinished is true I just paint the views.